# How to pass env variables through ssh to an user redirect to chroot

Tags: ssh, chroot, sshd

I need to isolate some users in a chroot jail, all works fine. But there is a last remaining issue: for these users (redirected to the chroot), the env variables coming from the ssh client are lost.

For example, my users send the env **LANG** though their ssh client, and this variable is in the *AcceptEnv* list of the **sshd_config** file,
but it is not passed to the chrooted user sessions, even if it works perfectly for the non chrooted ones.

Here is my **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** update:

```
AcceptEnv LANG MY_SPECIFIC_VARS_*

Match Group chrooted
    ChrootDirectory /chroot
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    X11Forwarding yes
    X11DisplayOffset 10
    X11UseLocalhost yes
    AllowAgentForwarding yes
    PermitRootLogin no
```

Sadly:

- this variable cannot be set in the .ssh/environnements file, because it is fixed at runtime.
- the "*Directive 'AcceptEnv' is not allowed within a Match block*"
- my version of sshd is: **OpenSSH_5.3p1**, and I cannot upgrade it.

Is there a solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce it from the server side if you don't want to add it it to the global scope of config. Thought there are some possibilities:

- Run different service on different port for chrooted users and add the `AcceptEnv` there (without Match).
- Client side solution, if there is not much of the variables (can be bash alias or function):

  ```
  ssh server "MY_SPECIFIC_VARS=$MY_SPECIFIC_VARS bash"
  ```
- As you note, update of whole server (CentOS 6?) would make sense. Current openssh supports `AcceptEnv` in `Match` blocks.

Comment: I do not understand, the variables are added to the global scope, in the AcceptEnv of the /etc/ssh/sshd_config anyway.
What do you mean ?

As for the update of the servers, I would gladly use this solution if I was the one managed them, but nit is not the case and I foreseen their update to CentOS 7.0 not before several years :-)

Comment: exactly as it was in your example config. Putting the `AcceptEnv` out of the `Match` block. It will accept this variable for all the users, but it should not matter, isn't it? Also don't forget that you need to add `SendEnv` in the clients appropriately.